# Rancher Desktop - Nerdctl --output

Tags: rancher-desktop, nerdctl, containerdctl

I have installed Rancher Desktop.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2 AS base

RUN yum install -y python3
...
RUN mkdir /output && venv-pack -o /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/pyspark_deps.tar.gz .
```

When I run the following:

```
$ nerdctl build . --output type=local,dest=.
```

The output file ends up in the Rancher Desktop node (virtual machine):

```
$ rdctl shell
$ cd /
$ ls
bin  containers  dev  etc  init  lib  lost+found  mnt  proc  pyspark_deps.tar.gz  root ...
```

I would have expected pyspark_deps.tar.gz to be in the folder I ran nerdctl from. Is this a bug? This is the way I usually get a file out of an image with Docker...